# How to sort files into folders by filetype on bash (with 'file' command)?

Tags: linux, bash, file, file-type

I have  thousands of files without extensions after recovery (mostly pictures). I need to sort them into separate folders by filetype (folders must be created during sort process). I can determine filetype in linux using "file" command. Does somebody have bash script for it?

For example: Initial dir contains files: 001, 002, 003, 004. After sorting should be 3 dirs:
'jpeg' contain 001.jpg, 003.jpg; 'tiff' contain 002.tiff and 'others' contain 004.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer does not execute `file` command multiple times for each file, which is unnecessary

```
file  -N --mime-type -F"-&-" * | awk -F"-&-" 'BEGIN{q="\047"}
{
  o=$1
  gsub("/","_",$2);sub("^ +","",$2)
  if (!($2  in dir )) {
    dir[$2]
    cmd="mkdir -p "$2
    print cmd
    #system(cmd) #uncomment to use
  }
  files[o]=$2
}
END{
 for(f in files){
    cmd="cp "q f q"  "q files[f]"/"f".jpg" q
    print cmd
    #system(cmd) #uncomment to use
 }
}'
```

similarly, can be done with bash4+ script using associative arrays.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
mkdir -p `file -b --mime-type *|uniq`
for x in `ls`
do
        cp $x `file -b --mime-type $x`
done
```

I use cp, it can't work with directories.

Comment: You are right, thanks, but there are some shortcomings (see adjustment).

Comment: You could use `for x in *`

Answer (score 3):

Dadam's answer adjustment:

```
#!/bin/bash

file --mime-type -F"&" [YOUR PATH]/* > filetypes.txt
mkdir -p `cut -f2 -d"&" filetypes.txt | sed 's/[ ,:]//g' | sort -u`
IFS=$'\n'
for x in `cut -f1 -d"&" filetypes.txt`
do
  mv "$x" `file -b --mime-type "$x" | sed 's/[ ,:]//g'`
done
```

Comment: The issue here is, it replaces the file with same name. for example, if there is a filetype results.txt, and another results.txt. It does not save it as a 2 different files. You end up with only one results.txt

Answer (score 2):

I use this and it works for me :

```
#!/bin/bash

self_name=`basename "$0"`
for f in *
do
    if [  -f "$f" ] && [ "$f" !=  "$self_name" ]; then
        filename="${f%.*}"
        ext="${f##*.}"
        mkdir $ext

        mv "$f" "$ext/$f"

        htmlfiles="{$f}_files"
        if [ -d "$htmlfiles" ];then
            mv "$htmlfiles" "$ext/$htmlfiles"
        fi

        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
            then
            echo "Error: Failed mv $f"
        fi
    fi

    if [  -d "$f" ];then
        mv "$f" "$ext/$f"
    fi
done
```

You should put it in your directory and run it and it make a sub directory for extension